# Javascript closure defined elsewhere

Tags: javascript

Here is a trivial use of a closure:

```
function Thing() {
    var _x;
    return {
        setX: function(val) { _x = val; },
        getX: function() { return _x }
    };
}

var a = Thing();
var b = Thing();
a.setX(12);
b.setX(23);
a.getX(); //returns 12
```

What I want to do is be able to define the implementation of `setX` and `getX` outside the definition of `Thing`.

I tried something like this:

```
function setXimpl(val) {
    _x = val;
}

function getXimpl() {
    return _x;
}

function Thing() {
    var _x;
    return {
        setX: setXimpl,
        getX: getXimpl
    };
}

var a = Thing();
var b = Thing();
a.setX(12);
b.setX(23);
a.getX(); //returns 23 not 12!
```

It's pretty obvious that `setXimpl` and `getXimpl` are setting/reading some globally scoped `_x`, rather than inside the closure.

I tried a bunch of other stuff (mostly syntactical changes), but I just can't get an outside function to be a part of the `Thing` closure. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I can only imagine a case like this if you want to expose a public API, but there are easier ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very short answer to your question is no.

Closures work on the principle of accessing variables within function scope which are not accessible in global scope. This only occurs when the function doing the getting/setting are nested functions within a function that has returned (creating the closure). This implies new functions for setX and getX have to be created each time `Thing` is called, as in your `Thing` code.

This doesn't mean that functions returned from Thing can't call functions closer to global scope that are static by using (say) a IIFE
to define Thing:

```
var Thing = function(){

  function a(...) {...}; // create once
  function b(...) {...}; // create once
  return function () {   // the Thing function (create once)
      var _x;
      return {
          setX: function(val) { _x = val; },
          getX: function()    { return _x }
      };
     };
 }();
```

effectively giving the anonymous getter and setter functions access to statically defined encapsulated function helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Try a factory:

```
function setXimplLoader(x) {
  return function setXimpl(val) {
    x.value = val;
  };
}

function Thing() {
  var _x = { value: '' };
  return {
    setX: setXimplLoader(_x),
    getX: function() { return _x.value; }
  };
}

var a = Thing();
var b = Thing();
a.setX(12);
b.setX(23);

console.log(a.getX())
```

Or use some utility library:
https://lodash.com/docs#partial